# LinkedList CMULT a method that return a linked list

Tags: java

Write a method public static LinkedList CMult(LinkedList L1) that takes single LinkedList L1 and creates a new LinkedList L2, of the same length, such that node i of L1 contains the multiplication of the data in L1's nodes up to and including node i of list L1. Write a method main for the scenario below.
For example: Invoking the method CMult with the below L1 returns the following L2.
[see image to understand the concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbAqa.png)
i need help please

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please don't ask for help until you make some headway yourself. Be specific with your question. This is an assignment dump.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<L1.length;i++){
   int temp=1;
   for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
      temp*=L2[j] ;
      } 
    L2.add(temp)
}
```

There you go
I apologize for the untidy answer, I am typing from my phone.

Comment: thanks man but that's for the array i need it for linkedlist not the array

Comment: Logic is the same, just implement it and handle the errors as you go.

Answer (score 0):

public LinkedList cmult(LinkedList L1) {

```
Node w = L1.head ; 
LinkedList L2 = new LinkedList() ; 
Node prev = null , curr  ;

curr = L2.head ; 

int n ; 
int mult = 0 ; 
int mult2 = 0 ; 

while(L1.head !=null)
    if(prev==null)
    { n= w.data.num ; 
      prev=L2.head ;    }         
    else  {   
        mult = w.next.data.num ; 
        mult2= prev.data.num ; }
        n=mult*mult2 ; 



  NodeData np = new NodeData(n);
  L2.addTail(np); 
  prev=curr ; 
  curr=curr.next ; 
  w = w.next ; 



return L2 ; 
    }
```